# Why does adding a Javascript Alert change this code's behavior

Tags: javascript, alert

I am using AJAX to populate a select-box called 'Duration' from a database. Users can choose the duration and submit the form. The results from the database are then listed on the same page. I am then using this PHP/Javascript code to set the select-box back to the user's choice.

```
echo "<script>alert(); document.getElementById('duration').value = '" . $xDuravar . "';</script>";
```

For some reason, only if I use the Alert(), the correct choice shows up on the select-box. Or else, the select-box reverts back to its default value. Why does this happen? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because the code is run before the target element has been parsed into the DOM. Try wrapping everything inside `window.addEventListener('load', function(){/* ALL YOUR CODE HERE */});`

Answer (score 1):

The document is not yet loaded when your JS code executes, it cannot find the `#duration` element.

The reason why it works when you add the `alert` is that JavaScript execution is stopped until you dismiss it, so then the document is loaded.

The "normal" way to fix that is to wait for the document to be loaded:

```
echo "<script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            document.getElementById('duration').value = '" . $xDuravar . "';
        }, false);
      </script>";
```

**On a side note**

If you use `DOMContentLoaded`, it will only wait for the DOM (basically the HTML) to be loaded (sufficient for the code you posted). However, if you use `load`, as suggested in Siguza's comment, it will also wait for any image, CSS, JS file to be loaded. So you might use one or the other, based on your needs. If you don't know which one you should choose, just use `load`.

Comment: Awesome! It's working perfectly. Thank you for your timely help. You and @Siguza saved me a lot of anguish and frustration. The rest of the site was working perfectly, except for this tiny hitch, which was ruining everything. Now everything's fine. Thanks a million!